# How to extend relation between two entities without losing data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'd like to extend existing relation between two entities without losing the data. That's ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web App.

I've got `Cars` and `Navs` (GPS sets). Specific `Car` could have a specific `Nav` and vice versa Specific `Nav` could be in a specific Car. However, `Nav` could be in a warehouse so it's not in any Car and specific Car could not have any `Nav` at the moment. Of course the specific `Nav` could be max in 1 car and specific Car could have max 1 Nav.

I've got relation between `Navs` and `Cars`. I'd like to add also relation between Cars and `Nav`s to easily pull from Car level data about `Nav` system that's there at the moment (if any).

Now I have following setup:

```
public class Car
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
 //other properties
}
public class Nav
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal ScreenSize { get; set; }
 //other properties
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

All I'd like to do is to add to `Car` class:

```
public virtual Nav Nav { get; set; }
```

But when I run `Add-Migration` it drops current relation so if I understand correctly I lose all data I have so far... That's what I get after `AddMigration`:

```
migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
    name: "FK_Navs_Cars_CarID",
    table: "Navs");

migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
    name: "IX_Navs_CarID",
    table: "Navs");

migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
    name: "CarID",
    table: "Navs");

migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
    name: "ID",
    table: "Navs",
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(int))
    .OldAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_Navs_Cars_ID",
    table: "Navs",
    column: "ID",
    principalTable: "Cars",
    principalColumn: "ID",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

What's the best way to maintain current relation & data and add relation from other side having both optional?

ADDED for clarification:
With current relation I could easily pull data about `Car` from `Nav` level:

```
  var modelName = nav.Car != null ? nav.Car.ModelName : "";
```

I'd like to do the same other way too:

```
  var screenSize = car.Nav != null ? car.Nav.ScreenSize : 0;
```

Comment: Please also show the model as you intend to make it + the old and new mappings.

Comment: @GertArnold As mentioned, I'd like to slightly modify Car class by adding to it: `public virtual Nav Nav { get; set; }`, but when I do it, Add-Migration drops current FK... Now I could easily pull data for Car from Nav level like: `var modelName = nav.Car != null ? nav.Car.ModelName : ""`. And I'd like to do it also other way so: `var screenSize = car.Nav != null ? car.Nav.ScreenSize : 0`. Hope it clarifies the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Before you added this property, EF was actually creating a one-to-many association. By adding this property, you're making it one-to-one. With a one to one, EF must define a principal end and dependent end (in other words, which one gets the foreign key). You can customize this, if you need to, but short of that, EF will make its own choice, and the situation here simply seems to be that it's choosing the opposite end from what you actually want. Therefore, you just need to add some fluent config to be explicit about what you want:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Nav)
        .WithOne(p => p.Car)
        .HasForeignKey<Nav>("CarID");
}
```

Comment: Thx for answer. Unfortunately, it hasn't solved the problem. FK's still dropped as Add-Migration wants to first change the column to not nullable. Here is the outcome
`migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(name: "FK_Navs_Cars_CarID", table: "Navs"); migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(name: "CarID", table: "Navs", nullable: false, oldClrType: typeof(int), oldNullable: true); migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(name: "FK_Navs_Cars_CarID", table: "Navs", column: "CarID", principalTable: "Cars", principalColumn: "ID", onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);`
Should I first alter column & change nulls to 0s?

Comment: Follow up to the comment above: Or maybe that' save to run that migration wihout losing current relations? Would it just drop the FK for a moment, change nulls to 0s on it's own and then recreate relations using existing CarIDs or rather it'd delete all existing CarIDs?